# Monthly Percentage Calculation

Tags: spotfire

Trying to calculate monthly percentage to be used to cumulative running percentage. I created a calculated column using `case when [defect_qty]=1 then 1 else 0 end` and the name is `[DefectQty]`. I also created calculated column to get total defect qty by month but I'm getting an error. This is the code `sum([DefectQty]) over ([po_created_month])` but I'm getting an error.. it says that the external data source doesn't not support *OVER* expressions.

By the way i'm new to this forum and spotfire.

```
po_created_month    sdesc   defect_qty  volume_qty
2016-01          PCB :      1         1
2016-01          PCB :      1         0
2016-01          NULL       0         1
2016-01          NULL       0         0
2016-01          NULL       0         0
2016-01          Lifted     1         1
2016-01          NULL       0         0
2016-01          Device h   1         1
2016-01          NULL       0         1
2016-01          NULL       0         1
2016-01          Device h   1         1
2016-01          Device l   1         1
```

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you've added data to your analysis as [in-database](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-analyst/7.5.0/doc/html/WebHelp/data/data_overview.htm) data. check that help link for more info. the simplest solution is to use the information modeler and create the data as an information link.